# How to connect android to hive which is installed in aws ec2 instance?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-ec2, hive

I have installed hive(2.1.1) on Hadoop(2.7.3) in aws ec2 Ubuntu instances. I written some queries and able to run on hive. But I wanted to connect android app to this hive or instances. so that I can run hive queries and get the result on android. how can I do this?

Comment: Can you describe your problem with more details? Which version of hadoop or hive? What your android app is? you want to run hive queries or just want to connect to ec2 instance?

Comment: i have edited question ,is the question now answerable ?

Answer (score 0):

Without having done this:

You could have another EC2 instance that runs a web server and communicates with your hive database to serve the results to your android device.

Another possibility is to have a Lambda function be the "web server" and serve the results. Then you could use API gateway to manage your Lambda functions if they are numerous.

Hope this helps.